# SheetJS xlsx-style need cell style in excel

Tags: javascript, excel, styles, export, xlsx

I am trying to export excel using SheetJS/xlsx and want to format cell. I am using following code and excel is generating but can't format a cell. Can any one point the issue or can share a complete sample code for this?

Loading library files

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sheetjs.com/demos/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

Remaining code are

```
function Workbook() {
    if(!(this instanceof Workbook)) return new Workbook();
    this.SheetNames = [];
    this.Sheets = {};
}

function sheet_from_array_of_arrays(data, opts) {
    var ws = {};
    var range = {s: {c:10000000, r:10000000}, e: {c:0, r:0 }};
    for(var R = 0; R != data.length; ++R) {
        for(var C = 0; C != data[R].length; ++C) {
            if(range.s.r > R) range.s.r = R;
            if(range.s.c > C) range.s.c = C;
            if(range.e.r < R) range.e.r = R;
            if(range.e.c < C) range.e.c = C;
            var cell = {v: data[R][C],
                  s: { alignment: {textRotation: 90 },
                       font: {sz: 14, bold: true, color: #FF00FF }
                };
        //cell.s = {}
       /*var cell ={ v: '2.4.2014',
        t: 's',
        r: '<t>2.4.2014</t>',
        h: '2.4.2014',
        w: '2.4.2014',
        s: 
        { patternType: 'solid',
          fgColor: { theme: 8, tint: 0.3999755851924192, rgb: '9ED2E0' },
          bgColor: { indexed: 64 } } };

      */
            if(cell.v == null) continue;
            var cell_ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C,r:R});

            if(typeof cell.v === 'number') cell.t = 'n';
            else if(typeof cell.v === 'boolean') cell.t = 'b';
            else if(cell.v instanceof Date) {
                cell.t = 'n'; cell.z = XLSX.SSF._table[14];
                cell.v = datenum(cell.v);
            }
            else cell.t = 's';

            ws[cell_ref] = cell;
        }
    }
    if(range.s.c < 10000000) ws['!ref'] = XLSX.utils.encode_range(range);
    return ws;
}
function s2ab(s) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(buf);
    for (var i=0; i!=s.length; ++i) view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
    return buf;
}
function GenerateExcelFile(inData, colWidth){
  var wb = new Workbook();
  var ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(inData); 

  var ws_name = "SheetJS";  

  /* add worksheet to workbook */
wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
/* TEST: column widths */
ws['!cols'] = colWidth;

var wbout = XLSX.write(wb, {bookType:'xlsx', bookSST:true, type: 'binary'});
saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],{type:"application/octet-stream"}), "test.xlsx")

}
```

Calling with these code

```
var excelData = "JSON DATA";
  var wscols = [
    {wch:30},
    {wch:20},
    {wch:20}
];

<button onclick="GenerateExcelFile(excelData,wscols)">Export</button>
```

Please help me finding out where I am wrong.

Thanks
Suman

Comment: Just realized there has less `}` at `cell style` section and causing syntax error. complete one is `var cell = {v: data[R][C],
                  s: { alignment: {textRotation: 90 },
                       font: {sz: 14, bold: true, color: "#FF00FF" }}
                };`

Comment: were you actually able to color the style with  SheetJS/xlsx ?

Comment: Sorry not yet :(

Comment: I solved it with using xlsx-populate (for people reading in the future)

Comment: @JochemQuery, from the future, thank you very much!!

Comment: @PauloGaldoSandoval I cannot build with xslx-populate :( (using vue and webpack) issue #74 on the github page

Comment: I've already build many excel with it using angular (using the version to browsers). But thanks for your care :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do any style with SheetJs/xlsx module only in the Pro version , So you can use [exel4node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node) for easy styling